# SAPUI5 Select Drop Down Icon Missing

Tags: select, icons, sapui5

I have an odd issue. Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/x8BKd1zA55I7WQBC0mOu?p=preview

The issue is that the icon on the drop down button does not appear when placing a sap.m.Select within a sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm. The Plunker includes the same elements on two different panels (sap.m.Panel) but one of the panels has the elements also within a SimpleForm.

[image: Sample]

Here is the XML:

```
<Panel>
    <Label text="One" />
    <Select>
      <core:Item text="Celsius" key="C"></core:Item>
      <core:Item text="Fahrenheit" key="F"></core:Item>
    </Select>
</Panel>
<Panel>
  <forms:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
    <Label text="One" />
    <Select>
      <core:Item text="Celsius" key="C"></core:Item>
      <core:Item text="Fahrenheit" key="F"></core:Item>
    </Select>
  </forms:SimpleForm>
</Panel>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Related GitHub Issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1940

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set simpleform as editable=true

```
<Panel>
    <Label text="One" />
    <Select>
      <core:Item text="Celsius" key="C"></core:Item>
      <core:Item text="Fahrenheit" key="F"></core:Item>
    </Select>
</Panel>
<Panel>
  <forms:SimpleForm editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
    <Label text="One" />
    <Select>
      <core:Item text="Celsius" key="C"></core:Item>
      <core:Item text="Fahrenheit" key="F"></core:Item>
    </Select>
  </forms:SimpleForm>
</Panel>
```